# Create multiple svgs in a html file with different attributes

Tags: html, css, svg

I worked my way through some HTML and SVG, but CSS is quite new to new. Therefore, I would like to start with a minimal example:
Lets assume I have a SVG file, which I can include in HTML, e.g., like this

```
<object data="picture.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="220" height="60">
```

So far, so good. But now I would like to have four of the same SVGs (assuming that the SVG file was only one path), but each one with a different color (without local copies of course).

If this works: What is the next step to add hover functionality to change the color?

Thanks for any hints,
curator

Comment: See this [**SVG Tutorials**](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

You should use anchor tags for all four files. You can then set the color to change by putting the following in you CSS file:

```
a:hover {
   color: whateverColorYouWant;
}
```